# Convert date time in another timezone with offset value in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, datetimeoffset

I am fairly new to ruby. I have a date value say "2014-12-15T19:56:59Z" and an offset value say "-06:00". How can I convert the given date time in the timezone given by offset value.

Comment: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html

Comment: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/Time.html#method-i-getlocal

Comment: BTW, −06:00 is an _offset_ and multiple time zones can have this offset during the year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`Time::parse`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.2/libdoc/time/rdoc/Time.html#parse-method) and [`Time#localtime`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/Time.html#localtime-method):

```
require 'time'

t = Time.parse('2014-12-15T19:56:59Z')
#=> 2014-12-15 19:56:59 UTC

t.localtime('-06:00')
#=> 2014-12-15 13:56:59 -0600
```